# How to link a asset folder outside the main index file path

Tags: php, filepath

So i have a folder that contains index file and other folders that linked together in the same file
i want to change the assets folder and move it outside the main folder
for example

Original File Location //

```
F:\Antex\Antee20\docs\folder\content\addons\myphpapp\assets
```

I want to change the path to //

```
  F:\Antex\Antee20\docs\folder\content\assets
```

(there's a folder in that area [ the issue is it's not linking it ]

---

**The Full File Path**

```
F:\Antex\Antee20\docs\folder\content\addons\myphpapp
```

Files Inside My php app are :
app.php

data & modules (3)

assets ( folder)

readme.txt

In app.php folder this is how i define the assets folder

```
define( 'ASSETS_PATH', APPCI_PATH . 'assets/' );
define( 'ASSETS_URL', APPCI_URL . 'assets/' );
```

I tried to make it this way

```
  define( 'ASSETS_PATH', APPCI_PATH . '\docs\folder\content\assets' );
    define( 'ASSETS_URL', APPCI_URL . '\docs\folder\content\assets' );
```

i also tried to add " .. " before the \ like this ==

```
define( 'ASSETS_PATH', APPCI_PATH . '...\assets' );
define( 'ASSETS_URL', APPCI_URL . '...\assets' );
```

Comment: Try `../../assets`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks To ***https://stackoverflow.com/users/934966/jonnix***

```
He Said Try ../../assets
```